# Tricky ODE to solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following second order differential equation $$(2t-2)t\phi''(t) + (3t-2)\phi'(t) = 0$$
I can divide off the coefficient to get the following $$\phi''(t) + \frac{3t-2}{(2t-2)t}\phi'(t) = 0$$

However, at this stage, I am not sure how to proceed to find the solution to the equation. I do not have an initial solution so I cannot use the method of 'Reduction of Order' which I initially thought I would use. Ideas?

Comment: Your first differential equation is not the same as the second (where there is an additional $t$ in the denominator). Which one is the one you'd like to solve? Anyway, the hint given by KittyL will probably get you in the right direction anyways...

Comment: Is it $(2t-2)t$ or $(2t-2)$ in the fraction?

Comment: Apologies friends. It is supposed to be: $(2t-2)t$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: let $\phi'(t)$ be $y(t)$ and reduce it to a first order ODE.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I was able to get through the problem.